# React Native - how to re render a component every x milliseconds? "this.setState is not a function?"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, render

Alright, Im trying to update the properties and/or text of a component every x milliseconds. I dove into https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-interval-renderer and the likes, however I got errors pertaining to s.

Im now looking at simply [react native (IOS). how to update value date (millisecond)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42666828/react-native-ios-how-to-update-value-date-millisecond) however am having trouble formatting this to my file.

I have:

```
export default props => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Inter-SemiBoldItalic': 'https://rsms.me/inter/font-files/Inter-SemiBoldItalic.otf?v=3.12',
  });

  this.state ={
   color: "#fff",
   colorAnimTime: 36000,
   time: 0
  }

    setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        time: new Date().getMilliseconds()
      });
    }, 1000);


//------------------------------------------------------------------->
  if (!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  } else {

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: { flex: 1,
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
      textWrapper: {
        height: hp('70%'), // 70% of height device screen
        width: wp('80%'),   // 80% of width device screen
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      myText: {
        fontSize: hp('5.5%'), // End result looks like the provided UI mockup
        fontFamily: 'SequelSans-BlackDisp'
      }
    });

      return (
        <AnimatedBackgroundColorView
        color='#00acdd'
        delay={0.5}
        duration={36000}
        initialColor={this.state.color}
        style={styles.container}>
          <View style={styles.textWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.myText}>COLOR</Text>
          </View>
        </AnimatedBackgroundColorView>
      );
  }
```

The referenced answer uses `componentDidMount() {` to enclose the `setInterval`, however I get syntax errors if I put that where I currently have the `setInterval`

Now Im getting

> this.setState is not a function

And have tried binding the `setInterval` to the right `this` but I believe Im not understanding how to set up my file.

After 1000 ms I want to change the 'color' of my `<AnimatedBackgroundColorView>` and just reload the component. (so it animates again - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-animated-background-color-view )

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try using hooks for `time: new Date().getMilliseconds()` ? can you do something like `const [time, setTime] = React.useState(null)` `setTime(new Date().getMilliseconds())`

Comment: Can you provide an answer with complete code?

Comment: Does this first comment help at all ? did you try it

Comment: @BARNOWL I tried, however Im not sure I understood you and I get the warning " excessive number of pending callbacks"

Comment: You're getting an excessive number of pending callbacks, because you've created an infinite loop. The `setTime`, sets a new state which forces a re-render, which calls `setTime` again, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your component is written as a functional component, not a class. To create a stateful functional component, you need to use the hook `setState`. You're getting this error as there's no object property `setState` on the component or `this`. You'll also want to use the `useEffect` hook to set your interval.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default props => {
  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
    'Inter-SemiBoldItalic': 'https://rsms.me/inter/font-files/Inter-SemiBoldItalic.otf?v=3.12',
  });

  const color = "#fff";
  const colorAnimTime = 36000;
  const [time, setTime] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setTime(new Date().getMilliseconds));
    }, 1000);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);


//------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: Thank you. My only issue now is re rendering my View component.. how would I go about that?